# Magento CE 1.9 after_body_start shows again after end html

Tags: xml, magento

I added a custom block via local.xml (works great) - to display a div immediately after the open body tag, xml code below... and it works, but it also displays it again after the end html tag? I checked the template phtml files and they dont call after_body_start again... any help would be appreciated!

xml add code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
    <reference name="after_body_start">
        <block type="core/template" name="gcadd" template="page/custom/gcadd.phtml" output="toHtml" before="-" />
    </reference>
</default>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution... the code:

```
output="toHtml"
```

was the problem, removing that part stopped the duplicated content.